# Dockerfile to create image of spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gradle, microservices

I want to create Docker image for a spring boot application.It uses gardle as build tool.

In bitbucket repository  i could see below files are placed

```
    --> src
    --> build.gradle
    --> Dockerfile
    --> gradlew
    --> gradlew.bat
```

Now Dockerfile has below content

```
  FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
  VOLUME /tmp
  ARG DEPENDENCY=target/dependency
  COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
  COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
  COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
  EXPOSE 8080
  ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","eds.billnq"]
```

When i try to create image using Dockerfile i get error

```
    target/dependency/BOOT-INF library not found 
    target/dependency/META-INF library not found
```

My query is why here there is no gradle build steps in docker file ?
Also where target/dependency/ will be  created ?

Comment: refer to https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/

Comment: @ WonChul Heo I referred it but still i did not get why there are no gradle build steps in Dockerfile

Comment: Did you reference the settings [here](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot-docker/blob/master/complete/build.gradle)?

Comment: @WonChul Heo  yes i modified it too due to some errors.Apart from error my main question here is why we are not using build steps in Dockerfile ?

Comment: Well, I am not too familiar with spring, but the error you are getting is because target/dependency should actually be a directory in your machine. So lines 4 and 5 are basically trying to copy the BOOT-INF AND META-INF from within the target/dependency directory in your machine to the docker container. There is nothing in the Docker file to actually create the directory, it just uses it.

Comment: `bootJar` is included in the `build` task. So you don't have to use `build` directly. refer to [Spring Boot Gradle Plugin Reference Guide - 4.1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/)

Comment: @ WonChul Heo So this means i should have build code(gradle run) using gradle before creating Docker image ?

Comment: Gradle will create the docker image. There should be a docker task in thre which does that. All of that is explained in [the earlier mentioned guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/)

Comment: @ M. Deinum    Are you talking about below docker task ? If yes then why do we need Dockerfile if this creates docker image ?                                                                                                                       
                     docker {
    name "${project.group}/${bootJar.baseName}"
    copySpec.from(tasks.unpack.outputs).into("dependency")
    buildArgs(['DEPENDENCY': "dependency"])
}

Answer (score 0):

> why here there is no gradle build steps in docker file ?

It looks like the `Dockerfile` is expecting the application to have already been built (by Gradle) before the Docker image is built, and for the resulting class files and jars to be available in various directories under `target/dependency`.

The [Spring Boot Docker guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/) referred to by @WonChul Heo in the comments goes into how to build a Docker image using Gradle and specifically with the plugin `gradle.plugin.com.palantir.gradle.docker:gradle-docker`.

> Also where target/dependency/ will be created ?

I'm guessing they should be created when you run your Gradle build, but without knowing more about how the build is configured, it's hard to say for sure.

I suggest you read through the guide again and compare what it recommends to what you have in your codebase, especially the Gradle build definitions.

At the end of the day, if you've pulled code from a private code repo and can't figure out how to make it build, it's probably best to seek out advice from the people who've committed to the codebase than from SO.

Comment: In the given article if i want to build image then are below set of commands correct?    1. $gradle build  2.$gradle run  $docker build -t my-image .

Comment: The article provides several options for ways of working, but one of the main things it points towards is using the Docker plugin in Gradle. If doing that, you won't run docker build directly, but Gradle will do it for you. The page says: "You can build a tagged docker image and then push it to a remote repository with Gradle in one command: ./gradlew build docker". I can't see your whole repository, so I can't say exactly what commands will work, but if we think the creator of the repo followed that guide, it looks like you should be running `./gradlew build docker`

Answer (score 0):

When working With Gradle ur jar file is going to be generated inside  `build/libs/{Your jar}`

Can you please change `ARG DEPENDENCY=target/dependency` to `ARG DEPENDENCY=build/libs` and try? It will work.